# How can I make getting this number more efficient

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization

I am writing a piece of code that gets the price of a panel for a company. The price is determined by 4 variables. 1)priceLevel 2)gauge 3)color 4)panel. I will post what i have so far below. The code works fine but i am wondering if there is an easier, more efficient way. The price of the panel needs to be the value for var panelRate.

Price Level position

```
var priceLevel;
if (retailPrice.checked)
{
    priceLevel=0;
}
else if (contractorPrice.checked)
{
    priceLevel=1;
}
else if (wholesalePrice.checked)
{
    priceLevel=2;
}
```

gauge

```
var gauge;
if (gaugeNine.checked)
{
gauge="0";
}
else if (gaugeSix.checked)
{
gauge="1";
}
else if (gaugeFour.checked)
{
gauge="2";
}
else if (gaugeTwo.checked)
{
gauge="3";
}
else if (gaugeSeven.checked)
{
gauge="4";
}
```

color and panel type are defined just like the other two shown above but color goes from 0-6 and panel type goes from 0-9.

I then use the 4 numbers to find the position in an array (below) that holds the price that I need.

```
var panelPrice=[];
panelPrice[0]=[];
panelPrice[0][1]=[];
panelPrice[0][1][0]=[];
panelPrice[0][1][0][0]=1.99;  //R,GU,29,TR
panelPrice[0][1][0][1]=2.99;  //R,GU,29,RP
panelPrice[0][1][0][2]=3.75;  //R,GU,29,C4
panelPrice[0][1][0][3]=4.33;  //R,GU,29,C2
panelPrice[0][1][0][4]=5.51;  //R,GU,29,5V
panelPrice[0][1][0][5];    //R,GU,29,SS
if (panelWidth=="16")
{
    panelPrice[0][1][0][5]=6.11;  
}
else if (panelWidth=="12")
{
    panelPrice[0][1][0][5]=10.06;
}
panelPrice[0][1][0][6]=6.89;  //R,GU,29,UP
panelPrice[0][1][0][7]=7.71;  //R,GU,29,SF

panelRate=panelPrice[priceLevel][colorUp][gauge][panelUp];
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I have over 1100 possible combinations.

Comment: If the pricing works in a consistent way, such as all retail prices have a 75% profit margin, contractor 50%, and wholesale 25% then you could just give the values using multiplication rather than a database. I feel that there is probably an equation that could prevent the need for a database at all, but I would need the price list to see how it works.

Comment: Please don't tell me that `gaugeSix`, `gaugeSeven` etc. are `id`s of checkboxes...

Comment: They are for a radio group, and no there is no exact correlation b/w the prices.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net with what you have working so for. Easier whan we can see markup. Using traverse techniques, classes and some data attributes will simplify process

Answer (score 0):

Great question.

I would add those different checks into an array and loop through them. Try something like the following:

```
var prices = [retailPrice, contractorPrice, wholesalePrice],
    gauges = [gaugeNine, gaugeSix, gaugeFour, gaugeTwo, gaugeSeven],
    priceLevel, gauge;

// check prices
for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    if (prices[i].checked) {
        priceLevel = i;
        break;
    }
}

// check gauges
for (var i = 0; i < gauges.length; i++) {
    if (gauges[i].checked) {
        gauge = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!